# Python 3: pairwise iterating through list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, pairwise

I am looking for a nice pythonian solution to read two elements out of a list in Python 3. What do I need to write for ??? in the following code:

```
it = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x, y in ??? :
    print (x, y)
```

The desired output would be:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Also one could solve it with indexed for-loop. But this is also ugly (IMHO)

Comment: I saw this answer too. However the anser there was mainly for python2 and the answer for python3 did not work. What do you propose?

Comment: ? The solution works just fine in python 3 if you replace `izip` with `zip`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can scroll down past the first answer...

Comment: use [`zip(*[iter(it)] * 2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631256/6597761)

Comment: @Ivan your code worked. Thanks

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger try that https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572450/2572645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip(*[iter(it)] * 2)`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631256/6597761).

```
it = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x, y in zip(*[iter(it)] * 2):
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why  **for x, y in zip(it,it)** is not working?

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger `zip` will sweeps its arguments within the same step untill the minimum length of them. So, in your case `zip(it, it)` will yield `(1,1), (2,2),...`

Comment: @ChihebNexus : whereas `zip(*[iter(it)] * 2)` takes one element and duplicates it. I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way without zip is:

```
i = 0
while i < len(it)-1:
  print(it[i], it[i+1])
  i += 2
```

Comment: I agree it is easy, but it uses indexes: I try to avoid indexes whenever possible. But that's a matter of style

Comment: Yes it uses indexes. I did not have read this, sorry. But maybe someone else will help this. Luckily there are enough answers which will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Another cheap option, using indices. You might not like them, but they are fast.

```
it = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x in range(0, len(it)-1, 2):
    print(it[x], it[x+1])
```

Comment: I compleatly agree with you. My many years of C programming and buffer overflows hurt me a lot. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which will work in `Python3`:

```
def pair(a):
   # Or simply:
   # return zip(a[::2], a[1::2])
   for k, v in zip(a[::2], a[1::2]):
       yield k, v

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
final = list(pair(a))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Ansering exactly the question the answer for the question marks would be: `zip(a[::2], a[1::2])` . In my opinion a very readable answer. Congratulation.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work for your case:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(*[' '.join([str(a) for a in x]) for x in zip(l[::2],l[1:][::2])],sep='\n')
```

First I had to use l[::2] to create a list the odd numbers in the list, then l[1:][::2] to get even numbers.  Did this using slicing function which is quite useful [link](https://coderwall.com/p/rujmya/get-odd-and-even-indexed-values-from-list-in-python)

Then I zipped them together to match 1st, 2nd, 3rd elements etc [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Then I used list comprehension to create a list of each of those sets.  The problem is that they were sets and not text as above.  To resolve this I changed my sets to string `str()` .

Now that the individual sets have been turned into string, you can join with `' '`.

You still have a set of 3 but you can print each line with print(*[list here],sep='\n') [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443588/how-can-i-format-a-list-to-print-each-element-on-a-separate-line-in-python)

Learned a few new tricks, hope this helps!

Comment: That's unreadable. This won't pass any code review on earth.

Comment: @aran-fey I'm sure OP is worried about peer review as he submits this to the platform he is building.  There are different approaches to solving problems on this site.  I combined a few different functions and explain and note source for each.  This site is educational and all solutions have merit

Comment: Dear @EoinS, you made me smile when I read your code. I am sure it will work. I liked how you used a real unusual approach to solve the problem: going over strings. However, imagine yourself reunderstanding your own code in a few years. It could be difficult.